# Que es lo que hace set_colorkey en PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

En la [documetacion](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) de PyGame indica que `surface.set_colorkey`, basicamente hace transparente el color que se le pase por parametro en la superfice sobre la que se aplique el metodo (`surface` en este caso) , en otras palabras, si hago `imagen.set_colorkey(pygame.Color('white'))`, esto hara que todos los pixeles en el surface `imagen` sean transparentes. Bien, ahora pongo este sprite de ejemplo ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este tiene un fondo blanco, pues bien, lo ideal para ponerlo en el surface principal (la ventana) seria eliminar ese fondo a traves de `sprite.set_colorkey((255,255,255))`, sin embargo, al hacer eso, la imagen empieza a tener un fondo negro ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, cuando pongo `sprite.set_colorkey((0,0,0))`, la imagen si pierde el fondo. De que me estoy perdiendo??

**codigo ...**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))
ruta_de_carpeta = '../data/sheet_sprites/enviroment/naturaleza'

# lista_de_imagenes = []
# for i in range(1, 7): 
#     ruta_de_imagen = ruta_de_carpeta + '/' + str(i) + '.png'
#     print(ruta_de_imagen)
#     imagen = pygame.image.load(ruta_de_imagen).convert()
#     lista_de_imagenes.append(imagen)

salir = False
frames_per_image = 10
current_image = 0
current_frame = 0
fps = pygame.time.Clock()
imagen = pygame.image.load(ruta_de_carpeta + '/1.png').convert()

while not salir:
    print(current_image)
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(imagen, (100,100))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            salir = True
    pygame.display.update()
    fps.tick(1)

pygame.quit()
```

PD: me estoy dando cuenta que el que provoca que el fondo de la imagen se ponga negro cuando el fondo de la ventana es blanco es el `.convert()`, alguna idea del por que?

Comment: Tu imagen ya tiene un fondo transparente. Por que usas set_colorkey? Hice un código con tu imagen y carga la transparencia a la perfeccion.

Comment: Sobre tu pregunta, la verdad no tengo idea... No logro crear un código donde ocurra lo mismo. Podrías agregar en la pregunta tu código por favor? A ver si en ese caso si ocurre.

Comment: @DanteS. el fondo de tu codigo era blanco o negro?, use set_colorkey por que , cuando el fondo de la ventana es blanco la imagen empieza a tener un fondo negro

Comment: Probé con fondo negro y blanco en ambos casos. Por eso quiero ver tu código. Quizá me estoy perdiendo de algo...

Comment: Para mi la documentación de Pygame está en lo cierto en cuanto al objetivo de set_colorkey.

Comment: @DanteS. aparentemente el responsable de este fenomeno es el uso de convert(), por que modifica la imagen?

Comment: Sip! Es responsable. En su lugar usa convert_alpha, que está pensado para imagenes con transparencia.

Comment: Lo logré reproducir! Y pude confirmar que el convert es responsable.

Comment: @DanteS. Grande, muchisimas gracias por estar tan atento :-)

Comment: Un placer c: Sobre tu pregunta de por que afecta la imagen, no tengo idea, pero según la documentación de pygame sobre convert dice que si la imagen tenía pixeles alpha estos serán eliminados.

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación de convert() dice lo siguiente:

> The converted Surface will have no pixel alphas. They will be stripped if the original had them.

En español:

> El Surface convertido no tendrá pixels transparentes (alfa). Estos serán eliminados si el original los tenía.

Así que ese el motivo por el que aparece el fondo negro. Los pixels transparentes son eliminados al usar el método convert(). La solución es usar convert_alpha() que sí respeta los alfa.